# Repeated wi-fi crashes after connecting a 12.10 server

Tags: wireless, server, 12.10

*I tried looking for another post about this, but they were all using wifi connection, while my problem is a little different.*

A few days ago I formatted an old computer and installed Ubuntu server 12.10 on that, to use it as a home fileserver (so I also installed samba and openSSH, as an online guide suggested).

I plugged in the Ethernet cable and straight since starting the installation, ***my WiFi network crashed***. From since it crashes every now and then, without forewarn or malfunctions, it simply stops working.

My WiFi repeater is also an Ethernet switch, so both the server and WiFi are plugged in there, one physically through Ethernet, the other being integrated in the switch. Luckily I can reboot just the WiFi by pressing a button on the repeater, but since I started the server project to have all files available on any device on the network.

When someone is looking at a video through a WDTV device the crash means he has to reconnect and start over, so rebooting it is not an option for me ..

*I must admit I'm more than just inexperienced with **Ubuntu**, so I would happily accept any suggestion.*

Comment: What brand/model of **WiFi router(s)** are you using? How much has traffic to your ISP increased, since installing Ubuntu server? Is this over **ADSL**, using PPPoE/PPPoA?

Comment: I think I'm using a Netgear WNR2000 (I'm not sure because i can't seem to find the package anywhere).

Comment: I didn't know pressing enter would send the post... however...
I don't think traffic to ISP increased, since i deactivated automatic upgrades to manage them manually and the server is only accessible via LAN/WLAN because I want to use it just as a local network storage (but I need to be able to upgrade it also hardware-wise, so something like a NAS is out of the question)

Comment: *I assume ..* you are using a single '**WiFi router**'. This is providing WiFi (to laptop/tablet, and TV), but also direct Ethernet connection for server. *Your use of 'repeater' is confusing.* ***Is this an ADSL router?*** Define 'crash', a 'lockup' or 'dropped connection' ?

Comment: I don't have a clear cognition of what i'm talking about, so I'll try to use the most simple terms I can come up with.
The adsl line arrives on a thing defined by the producer as 'HAG': I suppose it's actually a modem with three ethernet sockets, but still, it works as a switch as well as a modem.
One of the ethernet cables arrives from there to another device, which has an "in" ethernet socket and four "out" ethernet sockets. This device also creates the wlan.
The server and my personal computer are both plugged in the device via ethernet, while TVs and other devices are connected via wlan.

Comment: I forgot to define "crash"... the lan keeps working, i can still access the server via cable, i can access the internet (computer->device->HAG->web) but... the wlan stops working. no signal given, and I have to manually switch the device off and then switch it on to make it work again

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup.

I have a **Netcomm** ADSL modem (connected to phone line), which has an **Ethernet** connection to a **D-Link** 4-port GigaBit WiFi router.

---

***What might help:***

*I disabled **PPPoA** on the ADSL modem, and instead use **PPPoE** on WiFi router.*

This is now significantly more stable, as otherwise the ADSL router reset every 4-5 hours. It would usually auto re-connect, but would disrupt downloads, email, etc.

---

*Still unsure what might be causing the WiFi issue for you.*